# Error m_InstanceID != 0 when downloading texture from the server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, textures, webrequest

I'm getting this error in Unity 5.4 when trying to download the texture from the server.

Here is the code (the link should work):

```
     UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetTexture("https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/fc2beef90fad49f83d79650a10b5c030?s=256&d=identicon&r=G");
     www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "image/*");
     async = www.Send();
     while (!async.isDone)
         yield return null;
     if (www.isError) {
         Debug.Log(www.error);
     } else {
         tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);    // <-------------------
     }
```

The error looks like this:

```
m_InstanceID != 0
UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerTexture:GetContent(UnityWebRequest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a bug*. It happens when `www.isDone` or `async.isDone` is used with `DownloadHandlerTexture`.

The work around is to wait for another frame with `yield return null;` or `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame()` before calling `DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);`.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetTexture("https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/fc2beef90fad49f83d79650a10b5c030?s=256&d=identicon&r=G");
www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "image/*");
async = www.Send();
while (!async.isDone)
    yield return null;
if (www.isError)
{
    Debug.Log(www.error);
}
else
{
    //yield return null; // This<-------------------
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();  // OR This<-------------------
    tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);   
}
```

Although, I don't know how reliable this is. I wouldn't use this in a commercial product unless a thorough test is performed.

A reliable solution is to file for bug about `www.isDone`, then don't use `www.isDone`. Use `yield return www.Send();` until this is fixed.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetTexture("https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/fc2beef90fad49f83d79650a10b5c030?s=256&d=identicon&r=G");
www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "image/*");
yield return www.Send(); // This<-------------------

if (www.isError)
{
    Debug.Log(www.error);
}
else
{
    tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);    
}
```

Comment: Did you try your solution? I use the same pattern to read some json data and it works just fine - so it only breaks on texture loading? I'll try you solution and report later tonight

Comment: I do not think you read the answer. "It happens when www.isDone or async.isDone is used with DownloadHandlerTexture". It happens with a Texture but not with a text data. The problem is that `isError` is reporting finished when not finished. It would be good to make comments only after trying the answer to save both of us time.

Comment: I understood the answer, I'm just surprised that it only breaks on DownloadHandlerTexture.

Comment: Oh, ok.`UnityWebRequest ` is about 9 month old and is still new. There is still a-lot to fix. Try it when you get home and also file for a bug report too. I don't have time to do that.

Comment: Just verified your fix and it works. Going to make a sample project to submit for bug to Unity. ty

Comment: Nice. I will update this question when this is fix. Go ahead with the bug filing